How to approach a classification problem when your dataset has many features?
I have a timeseries health dataset that I wish to classify, however I'm getting confused on how to classify it due to the high number of features.
I've followed tutorials on classification using SVM, RF and PCA but they typically use datasets with at most a handful of features (e.g, the iris dataset).
How can I go about classifying this dataset which is 1 dimensional but with a large number of features?
I've provided an example dataset below. The dataset has a row for each new ECG measurement (a value between 0 and 1), 60 columns representing a measurement for each second and an additional label column which has 4 labels.


So you have 60 features? What's stopping you from using the methods described above for 60 instead of, say 6, columns?
